# class struct or interface method must have a return type in C#

Tags: c#, return-type

```
using System;
namespace studentObj
{
class Student
{
    private int id ();
    private string name ();
    private char grade ();

    public int ID
    {
        get {return id;}
    }
    public string Name
    {
        get {return name;}
        set {name = value;}
    }
    public char Grade
    {
        get {return grade;}
    }

    public Student(int ID, string Name)
    {
        int id;
        string name;
    }

    public SetGrade(float score)
    {
        if (score>=90.0f)
            grade="A";
        else if (score>=80.0f)
            grade="B";
        else if (score>=70.0f)
            grade="C";
        else if (score>=60.0f)
            grade="D";
        else
            grade='F';
        return grade;
    }

    public override string ToString(){
    }
    class Kid
    {
        private int id { get; }
        private string name { get; set;}
        private char grade { get; }

        public override string ToString ()
        {
            return id + "," + name + "," + grade;
        }
    }
}
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        Student student = new Student (Name = "Jasdeep", ID = "234");
        SetGrade.student=75.0f;
        Console.WriteLine (student);
    }
}
```

}

the error it says is from the SetGrade block and it is saying that i need to add a return type but I am confused as to what it is supposed to be. is it supposed to be grade or score or something else.

Comment: Assuming you've read help that Visual Studio provides when you click F1 on error message (CS1520 - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ecw87y92%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) it is not completely clear what you are confused with.

Comment: The function returns the variable `grade`. What is the type of that variable?

Comment: Use `void` if your function doesn't return any value.

Comment: @Shoe should be some other duplicate - that one was for incorrectly named constructor - clearly not the case here.

Answer (score 3):

It needs a return type, even if that type is `void`.  This method declares no such type:

```
public SetGrade(float score)
```

It *does*, however, try to return something:

```
return grade;
```

That something appears to be a `char`, so make that the return type:

```
public char SetGrade(float score)
```

Though, semantically, it doesn't seem like this *should* return anything.  The method advertises itself as a setter, and indeed should otherwise *be* a normal property setter were it not for the fact that it takes a parameter.  So just set the value with no return:

```
public void SetGrade(float score)
{
    if (score>=90.0f)
        grade='A';
    else if (score>=80.0f)
        grade='B';
    else if (score>=70.0f)
        grade='C';
    else if (score>=60.0f)
        grade='D';
    else
        grade='F';
}
```

(Note also that I replaced your strings like `"A"` with chars like `'A'`.  In C# you use single-quotes to make a `char` literal, which is very different from a `string` literal.)

---

Now, there are other issues here as well.  I've never seen this syntax before:

```
private int id ();
private string name ();
private char grade ();
```

If those should just be variables then you don't want parentheses:

```
private int id;
private string name;
private char grade;
```

Also, your constructor isn't actually doing anything with the values you pass it, it just declares variables within its scope and never sets them:

```
public Student(int ID, string Name)
{
    int id;
    string name;
}
```

What you *probably* wanted to do there was set the class' private variables:

```
public Student(int ID, string Name)
{
    id = ID;
    name = Name;
}
```

Though honestly you could simplify your properties using auto-generated properties.  The bulk of the class would then look something like this:

```
class Student
{
    public int ID { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public char Grade { get; private set; }

    public Student(int id, string name)
    {
        ID = id;
        Name = name;
    }

    public void SetGrade(float score)
    {
        if (score>=90.0f)
            Grade='A';
        else if (score>=80.0f)
            Grade ='B';
        else if (score>=70.0f)
            Grade ='C';
        else if (score>=60.0f)
            Grade ='D';
        else
            Grade ='F';
    }
}
```

This is more in keeping with C# naming conventions, reduces a lot of code, and really cleans up the overall look and feel of the class.  There's still more fixes and improvements to be made, both structurally and semantically, but I'll leave that as an exercise for your study.

Comment: He currently assigns string to grade, not char.

Comment: @EricJ.: He's inconsistent about that throughout the class.  I silently fixed it in mine, but you're right that it's worth calling out explicitly.  I'll make a note of it in the answer.